# list of lists to either autovivify or recursive data structure

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists in the format below. This is data coming from a csv and I am trying to emulate the data review function that excel has in python. The only reason I can't do it directly in excel is this document is almost 1GB and has 1.1 mil row.

```
((a1,b1,c1,d1,e1),(a1,b2,c1,d2,e2),(a1,b1,c2,d3,e3),(a2,b1,c1,d3,e4),(a2,b2,c2,d3,e5)...)
```

I want to convert it into a single data structure something like a multidimensional array. like below

```
((a1:(b1:(c1:(),c2:()),b2:(),b3:()),a2:(b1:(c1:()),b2:(c2:()),b3:())))
```

I use autovivify class for other purposes but I can't use it here because some of the keys I want to use are strings. Appreciate help here.

Comment: You should add an explanation of the "data review function that Excel has" since not everyone (including me) knows what that does.

Comment: I stand corrected. I am talking about the 'filter' function under 'data' tab when I am saying "data review function that Excel has".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to transform that list into a tree-like structure, where each tuple in the list represents one path down the tree. You can do this using nested dictionaries:

```
def add_to_dict(d, t):
    if t:
        first, rest = t[0], t[1:]
        nested = d.setdefault(first, {})
        add_to_dict(nested, rest)
```

Given a dictionary `d` (initially empty) and one of those tuples `t`, if that tuple is not empty, it takes the first element from the tuple, adds a nested dictionary to the original dictionary using this element as key (or takes one that already exists in this place), and adds the rest of the tuple to that dictionary in the same way.

Example using your data:

```
data = (('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1'),
        ('a1','b2','c1','d2','e2'),
        ('a1','b1','c2','d3','e3'),
        ('a2','b1','c1','d3','e4'),
        ('a2','b2','c2','d3','e5'))

d = {}
for t in data:
    add_to_dict(d, t)
```

The resulting dictionary `d` looks like this:

```
{'a1': {'b1': {'c1': {'d1': {'e1': {}}}, 
               'c2': {'d3': {'e3': {}}}},
        'b2': {'c1': {'d2': {'e2': {}}}}},
 'a2': {'b1': {'c1': {'d3': {'e4': {}}}}, 
        'b2': {'c2': {'d3': {'e5': {}}}}}}
```

Comment: yeah it worked. I had to modify the last part to get last two element in a list for third element, which I did and works fine. Thanks for the help :)